# How do I implement virtual methods in implementation files?

Tags: c++

C++ noob question:

lets say I want to use an abstract class with multiple methods as an interface:

```
// this is AbstractBase.hpp

class AbstractBase
{
public:
  virtual int foo() = 0;
  virtual int bar() = 0;
  // imagine several more pure virtual methods are here
};
```

I want a subclass implementing all the virtual methods, and I don't want to implement them in the header file, but in their implementation files instead.

Do I really have to declare all these methods again in the subclass declarations like this? I'm thinking there should be a way to avoid this step (coming from ObjC, Java)

```
// this is Concrete.hpp

class Concrete : public AbstractBase
{
public:
  int foo();
  int bar();
  // need to copy paste all the method declarations here again...? why?
};
```

what I would like to do is implement the methods in the implementation file like this:

```
// this is Concrete.cpp

#include "Concrete.hpp"

int Concrete::foo()
{
    return 666;
}

// etc...
```

but can't figure out how, without re-declaring the interface in each subclass.

Comment: That's how it's done, and you're doing it! Compiler needs the declaration, you can't just make up a definition - it's even in another compilation unit.

Comment: ok thanks - if the compiler needs this, it shall have it :)

Comment: Don't know about Objective C, but in Java you *cannot* even split declaration and definition of a method, so *"a way to avoid this step"* does not make sense. C++ allows you to merge definition and declaration if you want to, but it's often bad style.

Comment: in Java you can define an `interface` though, and you need to do it only once. if a class implements the interface, it has to implement all its methods and is thus safe. Protocols in ObjC work the same way mostly (though methods can be marked optional). pretty much was hoping for a CPP equivalent of that.

Comment: Um, "implement all its methods" is fine; "is thus safe" is nonsense. There are often good reasons for a derived class to only implement some of the pure virtual functions from a base class; the derived class is then also abstract. "Java doesn't let you do this" is not the same as "you shouldn't do this".

Comment: @spinalwrap: *"you need to do it only once"*? No, you have to repeat the method signatures in the implementing classes. *"if a class implements the interface, it has to implement all its methods"* Only if it is not abstract. *"a CPP equivalent of that"* C++ behaves pretty much the same here. If you don't implement all pure virtual methods in a derived class, then the compiler prevents you from instantiating it, just like you cannot instantiate an abstract class in Java.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although you can avoid writing function header signature for the second time if you combine the definition with the declaration "Java-style", i.e.

```
class Concrete : public AbstractBase
{
public:
  int foo() override {return 666;}
};
```

C++ does not let you avoid the *declaration* step when you want to provide your *definition* separately.

The reason for this is that the declaration is primary, while definitions are secondary. In order to be able to write

```
int Concrete::foo()
{
    return 666;
}
```

in your CPP file you need to tell the compiler that `Concrete` has an intention to override `foo` in its header.

Answer (score 6):

If you like an abstrct base class you have to make your methods pur virtual (only declaration without implementation (write `=0`behind the declaration of your method):

```
class AbstractBase
{
public:
  virtual int foo() = 0; // <- = 0 
  virtual int bar() = 0; // <- = 0
};
```

Use the `override` keyword, so you will get an compile error if decalaration of mehtod changes in base class:

Concrete.hpp

```
class Concrete : public AbstractBase
{
public:
  int foo() override; // <- override
  int bar() override; // <- override
};
```

Finaly implement your methods like you did it in your question:

Concrete.cpp

```
#include "Concrete.hpp"

int Conrete::foo()
{
    return 666;
}

int Conrete::bar()
{
    return 777;
}
```

**But you have to declare all those methods from base class in subclass which are abstract.**

Comment: The question was whether he can do it **without** having to list `foo` and `bar` in `Concrete.hpp`.

Comment: My compiler complains if I mix `virtual` with `override` - as it's a tautology - you can't override a non-virtual function.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, as LogicStuff said in their comment, you *are* doing it correctly.

Secondly:

> // need to copy paste all the method declarations here again...? why?

because your subclass

- doesn't have to implement *all* (or even any) of the virtual base class functions. It might override only some of them, and leave others to a more-derived class
- is allowed to add other methods and overloads.

  If you have a class with many methods, it'd be weird if you also had to look back through all its base classes (and all their base classes) to find other methods it might support but not have mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare all methods you want to override in the subclass.

You could use a macro to simplify this when done often. Define the macro in the header file of the base class like this:

```
#define ABSTRACTBASE_OVERRIDE_ALL \
    int foo() override; \
    int bar() override;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare all those methods from base class in subclass as well which you would like to implement.